# Divide Binary Numbers FSM

Tags: math, binary, clock, riscv, fsm

**Note: this question can be solved by math experts too.**

Today I learnt about FSM, My lecturer said for example if we are given a number in binary (being inserted from its MSB to LSB) we can decide if it's divisible by 7 using 7 states where each state indicates the remaining part.

But:

1. How can I decide when to move from one state to the other?
2. My professor said that for General number not always we need N states to decide if it's dividable by N or not, can someone please give me an example of such special case?

Comment: Trivial example for #2 is `N = 2` where you need no states at all since parity depends solely on the LSB.

Answer (score 1):

1. Work it out on paper. You have seven states, {0, 1, ... 6} for the possible remainders. Suppose the machine is in state 4; the remainder is 4. Then it receives the next bit, which is 1. Now what is the remainder? (Answer: 2) You must assign all fourteen of these transition rules.
2. Try it for n=6. You will see that there is no need for a state 4, since it is identical to one of the other states.

Comment: For 2 still I don't understand why we don't need 4, it's also a possibility 0,1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: @pdf20: Try it, think about it, you'll see it.